# How can I resolve Mongodb "Unsupported filter: Contains({document})" error

Tags: c#, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I wanted to forward notifications but couldn't proceed due to "Unsupported filter: Contains({document})" error. I wrote two queries, both of them were wrong. Both have same error

```
  var response3 = _notificationRepository.Aggregate()
            .Match(match)
           .SortByDescending(w => w.CreatedAt)
           .Skip((req.Page - 1) * req.PageSize)
           .Limit(req.PageSize)
           .Lookup<Entities.Models.Notification, NotificationLookedUp>("users", "UserId", "Id", "User")
           .Unwind(x => x.User)
           .As<NotificationLookedUp>()
           .ToListAsync();


 var response = _notificationRepository.GetWhereAsQueryAble(filterPredicate)
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
                     .Skip((req.Page - 1) * req.PageSize)
                     .Take(req.PageSize)
                     .ToList();
```

I get Unsupported filter: Contains({document}) error in these codes
[image]

```
how can i solve this error, Didn't fully explain the error in Exception
```

Comment: Can't see any problem based on your provided code. Please share the code, value for `match` and `filterPredicate` variable. Try to show some sample data and what is the expected result. Thanks.

Comment: see https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/frequently_encountered_issues/